# How do I copy & save GDrive files to my server using Google Apps Script / PHP?

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am working to create a script that scans our company Google Drive folders and copies any new files into a Repository directory on my server.

So far I can connect to GDrive, read all files, edit files, but I am unable to download via PHP. **`copy() file_get_contents() file_put_contents()`** etc. Are not working.

I imagine the solution is to use Google Apps Script to download and copy the file to my server directory, but I do not see the **correct class.methods** in the documentation.

How can I copy a **GDrive file** to my server using Google Apps Script?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to provide examples of the code you say is not working, since it is possible to copy files from Google Drive using the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/php) from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could run some code through Google Apps Script to upload the files to your server. In that case you need to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch`, which despite its name can also do an HTTP POST with arbitrary data. There is an example for uploading files in the API documentation.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app